# Condicion If en TRIGGER INSERT

Tags: mysql, trigger

Buen día comunidad. Tengo el siguiente Trigger funcionando bien, sin embargo, para optimizarlo deseo **introducir una condición** (Verificar si el campo `Ncliente` esta `inactivo==0` dicho trigger no se ejecute), es posible?

este es el codigo extraido desde phpMyAdmin

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `TR_add_credit` AFTER INSERT ON `cad_customer`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO 
    cad_cart_rule(
        id_cart_rule, id_customer, date_to, date_from, description, quantity,
         quantity_per_user, priority, partial_use, code, minimum_amount_currency,
         reduction_amount, reduction_currency, highlight, active, date_add, date_upd
    ) 
    VALUES( 
        NEW.id_customer, NEW.id_customer, NEW.copy_fpago, NOW(), 
        'Cantidad de crédito autorizado para pagar en el lapso estimado', 
        '1', '1', '1', '1', NEW.id_customer, '1', NEW.copy_credit, '1', '1',
        NEW.active, NOW(), NOW()
    )
```

De antemano, ¡gracias!

Comment: cuál campo Ncliente? en dónde está ese campo? en NEW, en la tabla, en otra tabla?

Comment: Esta en la misma tabla, en  NEW, pero por el momento no está en el TRIGGER, porque agrega un crédito  en todo registro (incluso cuando el campo Ncliente esta inactivo), y lo que deseo es que si está inactivo, no se ejecute

Comment: ¿Puedes aportar tu dataset para poder reproducir el problema? phpmyadmin, exportar.